# "Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component", but component does not have setState?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that takes a list of users from a URL using fetch, and is supposed to put them into a Table component. The fetch request is the standard

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/getUsers')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ ids: data })
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(this.props.url, err.toString()))
}
```

The problem seems to be when passing this.state.ids to child User nodes (each of which just takes an element from ids and renders it nicely). The User nodes also give the error "this.props.data is undefined", so it may be that the child nodes don't re-render after the parent updates state.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        tbody.push(<tr key={i} ><td><User data={this.state.ids[i]} /></td></tr>);
}
```

User only has a render(), and no calls to setState or anything. When the tbody.push line is removed, I no longer get the warning. There's another component that does something similar to this, but doesn't use a child component. Is there any way to make this work with a child component?

Comment: Not sure what the final answer is but two tips, one your key should be the actual id not the index. This keeps you from having key collisions. Two should you not loop to this.state.ids.length instead of 10?

Comment: For the looping, definitely, but right now I have it set to a larger value than it actually fetches to test the table pagination. Good tip about the keys, though, thanks.

Comment: Does your `Table` component's `constructor` have a `this.state = {ids: []}` initialization line in it?

Comment: It does. The values are passed in as

    <Table trHeading={theadings} tbody={tbody}
and the Table then sets the tbody state to this.props.tbody

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the issue is that on rendering the first time, there is no data from the fetch, and everything crashes. To fix, change render to be like this:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.ids.length === 0) {
        return (/*something not visible*/);
    } else {
        // everything else
    }
}
```

It will render initially as empty for a split second, and then re-render with the fetched data. It's not particularly elegant, but it does work.

Comment: To make it a little more elegant, return a loading indicator when `length === 0`. Style wise, maybe switch your returns. So, instead of checking `=== 0`, check `!== 0`, that way your primary return, ie. main component code, is at the top of your code, and your waiting state code is below. You could also use a ternary `return (!==0) ? <Component /> : <Loading />`